# Looping through asp:GridView data using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

First of all, is it even possible to loop through the data in an **asp:GridView** at **Client-side** using **JavaScript.** If Yes, I would like to know how to do that...

As I intend to capture the values of 2 fields on the Grid and attach an image on each row on the basis of their value(*that part shouldn't pose much of a problem once I can loop through the data and compare them*).

My Grid looks something like **this**:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" EmptyDataText="No Record Found" AllowSorting="true"
        AllowPaging="false" OnRowCreated="GridView1_RowCreated" Visible="true" BackColor="ButtonShadow"
        OnSorting="GridView1_Sort" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="None" >
        <Columns>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" SortExpression="Gender" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Age" HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="Age" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Type" SortExpression="Type" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Exam" HeaderText="Exam" SortExpression="Exam" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTime" HeaderText="DateTime" SortExpression="DateTime" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Priority" HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="Priority" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

*If I pitch it straight:* How do I capture *Gender* and *Age* for each row?

**P.S.** I am open to ***JQuery*** solutions too.......

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have the `id` of the gridview, you can grab the element in Javascript, iterate through its rows, and then the rows' cells, checking for index 1 (gender) or 2 (age), and get its `innerHTML` to get the contents. Take a look at this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var table, tbody, i, rowLen, row, j, colLen, cell;

    table = document.getElementById("GridView1");
    tbody = table.tBodies[0];

    for (i = 0, rowLen = tbody.rows.length; i < rowLen; i++) {
        row = tbody.rows[i];
        for (j = 0, colLen = row.cells.length; j < colLen; j++) {
            cell = row.cells[j];
            if (j == 1) {
                // Gender
                console.log("--Found gender: " + cell.innerHTML);
            } else if (j == 2) {
                // Age
                console.log("--Found age: " + cell.innerHTML);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZRXV3/

It definitely depends on the structure of your HTML that is rendered though. There could always be a hidden column or something.

---

**UPDATE:**

A jQuery solution may be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rows, genders, ages;

    rows = $("#GridView1").children("tbody").children("tr");    // Find all rows in table (content)
    genders = rows.children("td:nth-child(2)");    // Find all columns that are the 2nd child
    ages = rows.children("td:nth-child(3)");    // Find all columns that are the 3rd child

    // An example of looping through all "gender" columns
    genders.each(function () {
        console.log($(this).html());
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YgY35/

Comment: So technically a `<table>` should be comprised of a `<thead>` and `<tbody>`. It depends on what a `GridView` actually renders as - it may or may not take this form; it may just be `<table><tr></tr><tr></tr></table>`. `thead` is for column headers, while `tbody` is for the content (and `tfoot` is the footer). So if you can look at the rendered HTML, you can decide if you need the `tBodies[0]` part or not. If you look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/table.tBodies , it says there is always an implicit `tbody`, so I think it's safe to keep it and always use it.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher I just updated my answer with a jQuery solution as well.

Comment: Great answer @ianpgall! got to understand how it works.......though i ll keep the question open just in case smbody cms up wid another insight...

Answer (score 0):

I was looking forward for the same solution and I found above answer. When implemented, it didn't work in IE 11.

I modified the solution and did work in IE 11 as well.

```
var rOrders = new Array();
var table, tbody, i, rowLen, row, j, colLen, cell, tr;
var result = false;

table = document.getElementById("<%=gvRunningOrder.ClientID%>");
tbody = table.tBodies[0];
tr = $(tbody).find('tr');

for (i = 0, rowLen = tr.length; i < rowLen; i++) {
    row = tr[i];
    for (j = 0, colLen = row.cells.length; j < colLen; j++) {
        cell = row.cells[j];
        if (j == 1) {
            rOrders.push(cell.childNodes[1].value);
        }
    }
}
```