# Change color of text in ASP.NET table cell (according to value)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, colors

could you please help me with this:
I am creating a table of some items with their properties and values (over some time).
Looks like:

[image: Table]

I want to change color of those values, lets say 0 will be green 1 blue 2 red.

```
DataView dv = new DataView(grid);
myGridView.DataSource = dv;
myGridView.DataBind();
```

If I need to be more specific, please tell me, I am not a PRO. I don't know where can I control the cell.
I'd also like to add mouse over the text (so it will show the date of occurrence of current value).
Maybe some function/javascript...?

Comment: r u looking for javascript solution for doing the stuff ? then try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937122/looping-through-aspgridview-data-using-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple and light weight solution using jQuery:

**Code behind:**

```
public partial class GridViewCellColourChange : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            gvItems.DataSource = this.GetData();
            gvItems.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Item> GetData()
    {
        var item1 = new Item { item = "itm1", prop1 = "23", prop2 = "asd", prop3 = "23d", values = "0-0-0-0-0" };
        var item2 = new Item { item = "itm2", prop1 = "43", prop2 = "asd", prop3 = "23d", values = "0-0-0-0-0" };
        var item3 = new Item { item = "itm3", prop1 = "53", prop2 = "asd", prop3 = "23d", values = "0-0-0-0-0" };

        return new List<Item> { item1, item2, item3 };
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string item { get; set; }
    public string prop1 { get; set; }
    public string prop2 { get; set; }
    public string prop3 { get; set; }
    public string values { get; set; }
}
```

**.ASPX:**

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {  
            $("#gvItems > tbody > tr").each(function (i, row) {
                var children = $(row).children();
                for(var i=0; i < children.length;i++)
                {
                    var child = children[i];
                    if(child.localName == "td")
                    {
                        var text = $(child).text();

                        if(text == "23")
                        {
                            $(child).css("background-color", "red");
                        }
                        else if(text == "43")
                        {
                            $(child).css("background-color", "green");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvItems" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

**Output:**

[image: Change grid view cell colour based on value]

Answer (score 0):

You can use gridview control with **OnRowDataBound** property to bind specific properties to the each cell/Row.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I am trying with this one, I can actually change color of whole text. My problem is, I want to have different colors of text in one cell.

Comment: for that find the cell text in the OnRowDataBound and do whatever you want using..if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                string cellText = e.Row.Cells[1].Text.ToString();
            }

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnRowDataBound`Event of gridview,here is sample

```
protected void GridCompany_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gridViewRow in GridCompany.Rows)
        {
            if (gridViewRow.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if (gridViewRow.Cells[6].Text.ToUpper() == "TRUE")// find your cell value and check for condition
                { 
                   // put here your logic
                }
                else
                {
                   // put here your Else logic
                }
            }
        }
    }
```